# How does work SQL with order by 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case

How does it work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN field1 is not null 
    then 0
end, 
id DESC
```

I can replace 0 with other integer values but I still get correct result.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That reduces the values in the order clause to only 2 possibilities: null and 0.

Comment: You mean you can replace the zero with another number? ie. `then 6`

Comment: What do you consider to be the "*correct result*"?

Comment: yes, I can replace     'then 0'      with      'then 6'     and get the same result. But why?

Comment: @Paul you cannot replace that integer with anything higher than the number of fields in the select.

Comment: @Fred, that's not what he is asking about ... `0` is a literal here, not an ordinal.

Comment: @AHiggins My bad, read the whole thing incorrectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jurergen d pointed out, this reduces the possibilities in your `ORDER BY` to two candidates: `NULL` and *`n`*.  Whether *n* is 0, 6, 562, or 391842, anything in condition one (`NULL`) will show up before anything in condition two (*n*).

If, by "correct result", you mean "things with a `NULL` in Field1 show up first", then any number, positive or negative, would work as *n*.

Some sample data: it can be helpful to see what the `ORDER BY` clause is actually doing, so I'm going to duplicate that `CASE` statement in the `SELECT`.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Field1 INT, FieldSomethingElse VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (1, 'some')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (2, 'thing')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (765, 'or')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (NULL, 'another')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (NULL, 'thing')


SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN Field1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ItDoesn''t Matter What I Put Here, it is the same value for every non-NULL row' END AS ThisIsWhatYouAreSortingBy
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Field1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ItDoesn''t Matter What I Put Here, it is the same value for every non-NULL row' END, ID DESC
```

The purpose, as you probably already have figured out, is to allow your `ORDER BY` to use the `ID` field as the sort, but separate it out so that the rows with a `NULL` Field1 value come first.

Comment: Demo: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4be3e79/7](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4be3e79/7)

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY
CASE WHEN field1 is not null 
    then 0
end

NULL value will come first before all other value. So 0 or any other value does not matter.